# a4j:commandButton not submitting

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

In my xhtml, inside a `<h:form>` tag I have multiple panels, a4j:jsFunction and rich:popupPanel and a rich:panel. In my rich:panel I have a few text areas. Then, in another panel, inside a rich:popupPanel I have an a4j:commandButton that calls a a4j:jsFunction. What I want is when the a4j:commandButton is clicked, all data from rich:panel to be submitted. The following code is not submitting anything.

```
<h:form id="createId">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <rich:panel
                style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #6B489D; padding:30px">


        <rich:panel style="width:100%" >
                    <fieldset>

                        <table ...>

...some outputText, inputText...


  </table>
  </fieldset>
</rich:panel>

<rich:popupPanel id="confirmEditPane" autosized="true">
            <a4j:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmEditPane')}.hide(); return false;" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <h:outputText value="&#160;" />
            <a4j:commandButton value="Edit" onclick="edit(); return false;" />
        </rich:popupPanel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Each panel (Including the popup panel) should have its own `h:form`. Having one gigantic form with many elements within cannot end well, as you're already observing

Comment: Duly noted for next time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by adding `<p:ajas event="valueChange"/>` inside every panel containing textboxes and now everytime I change the value inside a textbox it gets sent to the server. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the attribute domElementAttachment="form" to your popuppanel.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Tried and didn't work though

Comment: It still doesn't send my data to the server.